# I can't load the .glb file in A-frame! How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, aframe

I'm new to a-frame and I tried to load the .glb file in A-frame but I can't see it in scene! How can i fix it? I have the code down below and also noted that it worked perfectly fine with .obj file.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% block threedtitle %}{% endblock %}

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene background="color: #EAEAEA">

        <a-asset>
            <a-asset-item id="toilet-glb" src="{% static '3d_file/toilet.glb' %}"></a-asset-item>
        </a-asset>

        <!-- Camera -->
        <a-entity position="0 100 100">
            <a-camera></a-camera>
        </a-entity>

        <!-- toilet -->
        <a-entity gltf-model="#toilet-glb" position="0 0 10" scale="0.08 0.08 0.08"
            animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; dur: 14000; easing: linear; loop: true">
        </a-entity>

    </a-scene>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what seems wrong but try this:

```
<a-entity gltf-model="src: url({% static '3d_file/toilet.glb' %})" ...></a-entity>
```

also check:

1. Are you sure about the `position` not at `0 0 0`?
2. The `scale` is so small!
3. Is `{% static '3d_file/toilet.glb' %}` return correct URL?
4. Maybe the `animation=` part cause some error?

Comment: This is good advice. First verify model on gltf viewer: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/. If it renders then check position (model might not be centered at 0.0.0), model might be to small or too big and camera is inside, check URL is correct (no 404s on console) and verify you're not having CORS issues. Sharing example with model and code that people can run will help people to help you https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Thanks bro but you are right the problem is about the position and scale. now i fix it thanks.